# Change text of a Graphics2D object

Tags: java, spring, aop, graphics2d

I have the below code, and I want to change text of Graphics2D object (g2D) from "Java" to a new String for example "Pascal".

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;    

public void paint(Graphics2D g2D) {

    FontRenderContext frc = g2D.getFontRenderContext();
    Font font1 = new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 24);
    String str1 = new String("Java");
    TextLayout tl = new TextLayout(str1, font1, frc);

    g2D.setColor(Color.gray);
    tl.draw(g2D, 50, 150);
}
```

Note that I have no access to the method body (this methodis part of a Jar file and so I have no access to the method paint), but I have access to the Graphics2D object (g2D) returned by method.

I am goint to use Spring AOP and use @After – Run to extract Graphics2D object (g2D) and then replace the text with a new one. However, I do not know how to do that. In one try, after I create a new TextLayout object with new text, but it adds new text on the previous text without replacing that (now I can see both text  - Java and Pascal).

Please let me know how can I change text of a TextLayout object added to a Graphics2D object.

Comment: First, you should not use `new String`. The string literal alone is a lot better in this case, as it'll re-use the same `String` object everytime. Use `g.drawString` to draw text.

Comment: As I said, I have no access to function paint, and I cannot change that.

Comment: What is the type of the class from where you have got this paint method? Secondly you could inherit this class and override the paint method in your class

Comment: yes, I can override the paint method, but it cannot help in my case. The method is part of a jar file which is called by other methods in jar file and if I override the method then I must change the code to call my override method when paint is called. (This is  a new question itself: How can I do that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem using [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/). Because TextLayout is immutable, it is not possible to change its value. Therefore, the best solution (I think) is to rename the current paint method and create a new one using Javassist. Therefore, in run time, my new method is called instead of the original one. The code is as below:

```
CtClass clas = ClassPool.getDefault().get("classFullName");

CtMethod mold = clas.getMethod("MethodName", "MethodParameters");

//Rename the original method name
String nname = mname+"$impl";
mold.setName(nname);
CtMethod mnew = CtNewMethod.copy(mold, mname, clas, null);

String bodyText = "New Method body";

 StringBuffer body = new StringBuffer();
 body.append(bodyText);

//Replace the body of the intercepter method with generated code block and add it to class.
mnew.setBody(body.toString());
clas.addMethod(mnew);

clas.writeFile();
clas.toClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use AOP in order to hook into this 3rd party JAR, you need to use AspectJ, not an "AOP lite" framework such as Spring AOP. This is because Spring AOP can only intercept public method executions for Spring components, not non-Spring stuff such as calls to JDK methods or constructors.

Intercepting the `paint` method `@After` the drawing is already finished is not going to help you either. Even if you intercept it `@Before` the drawing is done, it is not going to help you because the `Graphics2D` object is just a helper, a parameter to `TextLayout.draw`. Because `TextLayout` objects are, according to the API description, immutable, you would have to hook into its constructor call and modify the `String` parameter given to it. This is an ugly hack, but definitely possible with AspectJ if you set up compile-time binary weaving for the JAR or load-time weaving during runtime.

If you can show me more code or tell me which JAR is used in which way, I can answer more specifically, if this reply was not too technical for you already.

P.S.: Maybe it would be even better if you described what you actually want to achieve without thinking about *how* you think you should do it in the first place. Maybe there is a much simpler way to do it.